# Is it possible to use react-native-track-player together with react-native-video to show title and thumbnail on lockscreen?

Tags: react-native, lockscreen, react-native-video, react-native-track-player

We use react-native-video for a video application, the problem is when you lock screen during watching video, you get empty grey areas, we want to see video title and thumbnail there,

[image]

I have tried using react-native-track-player for title and thumbnail at the same time with video player but it does not work. If I use react-native-track-player alone I can see title and thumbnail, but if I use react-native-video for video but use react-native-track-player only for title and thumbnail I anymore see title and thumbnail.

Comment: I am also facing same problem, did you find something related to this ??